# What can you say about spread of data by looking at singular values and clusters?

Tags: clustering, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

I have dataset 250X5 and its singular values are [200 50 25.2 2.3 0.35].
Singular values are directly related to variance. Can you say something about the clustering of data and how much is the spread of data?

Answer (score 0):

Your have really big first three of the singular values compared to the last two. This means most of the variance of your points in 5 dimensions happens in a 3d space and the points are actually located very near this 3d space (clustered around a subspace of 3 dimensions) created by the three eigenvectors.

About the relationship of singular values and eigenvalues. The squared singular values obtained when you apply SVD to your matrix M of data is the value of the eigenvalues of the M'M (matrix product of transpose of M and M.)

Comment: Thank you so much! If I fit hyperplane in 5 dimensions can you comment on how many planes do I need?

Comment: That's true But Can I say this? , 'as major singular values are shows spread in 4 dimensions (By four singular values last is really small). only one 4d hyperplane is enough to cover all the major variability, So, I need only one Hyperplane or ~2-3' ?!

Comment: Sorry, I thought 3rd singlevalue was 2.52. I changed the explanation.  Most of the variance is in the space created by the first 3 eigenvectors. 4th singlevalue is already around one tenth of the 3rd. So you can say: a 3d vector space contains most of the variance. It is reasonable to project the data in a vector space of 3d, and this vector space is created by the first three eigenvectors.

Comment: Thanks a lot! @javierazcoiti